# Add indexes to speed up Geocoder near search

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my rails app I have functionality that allow to find users that are closest to currently logged in user. I'm using Geocoder gem for this. In User model I have scope like this:

```
   scope :close_to, -> (user:, distance:) {
    where.not(id: user.id)
    .near([user.latitude, user.longitude], distance)
  }
```

This works very well but it is slow on larger collection of users. When I call this scope it generates the following sql query:

```
SELECT users.*, 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((48.471645 - users.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(48.471645 * PI() / 180) * COS(users.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-83.102801 - users.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((users.longitude - -83.102801) / 57.2957795), ((users.latitude - 48.471645) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" != 43362) AND (users.latitude BETWEEN 39.4784289408127 AND 57.46486105918731 AND users.longitude BETWEEN -96.6674214298497 AND -69.5381805701503 AND (6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((48.471645 - users.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(48.471645 * PI() / 180) * COS(users.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-83.102801 - users.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1000) ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

I'm trying to create index for that but they not work. I was trying following combinations:

```
1.
    add_index :users, [:id, :latitude]
    add_index :users, [:id, :longitude]

2.  add_index :users, [:id, :latitude, :longitude]

3.  add_index :users, [:latitude]
    add_index :users, [:longitude]

4. add_index :users, [:id, :latitude]
```

How should I add index to speed up this query?

Edit: I forgot to add that my lattitude and longitude columns are decimals.

ANALYZE of this query returns something like that:

```
 Sort  (cost=7141.66..7142.14 rows=191 width=327) (actual time=575.995..585.543 rows=36598 loops=1)
   Sort Key: ((12742::double precision * asin(sqrt((power(sin((((((48.471645 - latitude))::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision) / 2::double precision)), 2::double precision) + ((0.662990616338754::double precision * cos((((latitude)::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision))) * power(sin(((((((-83.102801) - longitude))::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision) / 2::double precision)), 2::double precision)))))))
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4672kB
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..7134.43 rows=191 width=327) (actual time=0.381..517.615 rows=36598 loops=1)
         Filter: ((id <> 43362) AND (latitude >= 39.4784289408127) AND (latitude <= 57.46486105918731) AND (longitude >= (-96.6674214298497)) AND (longitude <= (-69.5381805701503)) AND ((12742::double precision * asin(sqrt((power(sin((((((48.471645 - latitude))::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision) / 2::double precision)), 2::double precision) + ((0.662990616338754::double precision * cos((((latitude)::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision))) * power(sin(((((((-83.102801) - longitude))::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision) / 2::double precision)), 2::double precision)))))) >= 0::double precision) AND ((12742::double precision * asin(sqrt((power(sin((((((48.471645 - latitude))::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision) / 2::double precision)), 2::double precision) + ((0.662990616338754::double precision * cos((((latitude)::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision))) * power(sin(((((((-83.102801) - longitude))::double precision * 3.14159265358979::double precision) / 180::double precision) / 2::double precision)), 2::double precision)))))) <= 1000::double precision))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 6756
 Planning time: 1.041 ms
 Execution time: 587.695 ms
(8 rows)
```

EDIT 2:

I noticed that postgresql uses my

```
add_index :users, [:latitude, :longitude]
```

only when I type small distance ex. User in near 10 kilometers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowdown is likely caused by math operations and not by fetching table data. Part of your criteria is not against record fields but against the outcome of the math operation on other records so it is becoming an O(N<sup>2</sup>).

The reason Postgres does not use an index and chooses Seq scan instead is because it decides that most of the table records will have to be fetched while querying. When most records in the table are to be fetched, indexes may not bring much benefit if any.

To speed things up you should consider using spacial indexes and vicinity-based search of [PostGis](http://postgis.net/) or, alternatively, Elasticsearch with [Geo Distance Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html).