# Rails geocoder find near locations within different radius

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

I want to find close locations for an user. ***Users table*** have their *latitude* and *longitude*.
***Locations table*** have their *latitude* and *longitude*. Also locations have a *radius* attribute. I want to find **locations** for an **user**, that the user is inside those locations within specific radius. I can't do `Location.near([user.latitude, user.longitude], radius)`, because all locations have different radius.

Also I cannot do `Location.all.to_a.select {|l| u.distance_from([l. latitude, l. longitude]) < l.radius}`, because it'd be inefficiently. It must be placed in the main page. Now I have about 1k locations and 1k users. 
How can I do that? I use gem geocoder, but I can use something else.

Comment: You could calculate relative distances yourself within SQL query but this will quickly become too slow on any significant amount of data. Take a look at [PostGIS](http://postgis.net).

Comment: Could you advise me how to develop typical solution? I cannot do Location.all.to_a.select {|l| u.distance_from([l. latitude, l. longitude]) < l.radius}, because it'd be inefficiently. It must be placed in the main page. Now I have about 1k locations and 1k users.

Comment: See this recent question on an example of the SQL query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058200/add-indexes-to-speed-up-geocoder-near-search/38059008. At your records count the performance may still be reasonable. On PostGIS this post is a place to start: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21903/how-do-i-perform-a-proximity-search-with-postgis and here is another: https://alternatelabs.co/blog/search-by-proximity-using-postgis.

Comment: What is the benefit of using index? Please look at my updated question or below
I have to do something like Location.all.to_a.select {|l| u.distance_from([l. latitude, l. longitude]) < l.radius}

Comment: You could do it this way in Ruby although it would be slower than done on the database level. This is why you need either an SQL query, which will only get you so far because of performance limitations or a specialized Postgres extension dealing with spacial search which is PostGIS.

Comment: Okay, I agree with you, but can you help me to make sql query first. I mentioned the ruby code, because I just wanted to clarify my problems.

Comment: You should try to make it first and if there is something specific you get stuck with, post a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115878/discussion-between-andrey-moroz-and-nic-nilov).